# Configure file missing for node.js v.0.8

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, compilation, installation

I just fetched node with `wget` from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.11/node-v0.8.11-linux-x86.tar.gz

I ran `sudo tar -zxf node-v0.8.11-linux-x86.tar.gz` and then `cd`'ed into `node-v0.8.11-linux-x86`. However the `Configure` file is not there, so when I run `./configure` I get a `no such file or directory` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't tell if it's the right one, but there's a configure file in `node-v0.8.11-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've downloaded a binary archive. With it, you should find `node`, `npm`, and `node-waf` already pre-compiled in the `bin` sub-directory.

If you want to build from source, you'll want to instead download:

http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.11/node-v0.8.11.tar.gz

Comment: that's strange, because the instructions in the readme file direct the user to run ./configure inside of the newly created node directory.